# Django rest framework pass field errors in the extra_kwargs dictionary

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am customizing the **does_not_exist** error message for a SlugField in my serializer as follows:

```
class PolicyCreateUpdateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    source_ip_group = serializers.SlugRelatedField(queryset=IPGroup.objects.all(), slug_field='name',
                                                   error_messages={"does_not_exist": "Custom"})
    enabled = serializers.BooleanField()

    class Meta:
        model = Policy
        fields = ['id', 'name', 'source_ip_group', 'enabled']
```

This works as expected.However, when I try to add this in the Meta attribute of the class, it does not work.

```
class PolicyCreateUpdateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    source_ip_group = serializers.SlugRelatedField(queryset=IPGroup.objects.all(), slug_field='name')
    enabled = serializers.BooleanField()

    class Meta:
        model = Policy
        fields = ['id', 'name', 'source_ip_group', 'enabled']
        extra_kwargs = {'source_ip_group': {"error_messages": {"does_not_exist": "Custom"}}}
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mentioning the field explicitly will be used and will ignore any `extra_kwargs` for the field.

Ref: [Serializer fields initialization](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/serializers.py#L1035)

Comment: so there is no way that I can pass the extra_kwargs ?

Comment: I think the logic is there to ignore `extra_kwargs` when declared field is used is because if you are declaring the field yourself, then you can mention all the things you require to override, while `extra_kwargs` are there to override a piece of the field, not the whole thing.